# What material can I put along a sharp, thin metal edge?

Tags: metal, rubber, sheet-metal

I have some sharp aluminum sheet metal, about as thin as a sheet of paper. I need to put something on the edge to protect other items from being cut by the edge. This could be a piece of rubber that fits over the edge, for instance.

The nearest product I can find is the edging on sheet protectors. It has a "U" shape, so you can clip it over. The problem is I need 200 ft! Is there a kind of product in the building world that serves this function? I looked through many window sealing strips, but could find nothing with a "U" shape that could fit over a thing sheet of metal.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just fold over the edge of the sheet metal?  I think that's the most common solution to this type of problem, and as a bonus it'll add strength to the sheet metal as well.

Comment: Did not know it is foldable.

Comment: Right, but compare the cost of just getting a bit bigger sheet and folding the edge vs buying some other material to protect the edge.  Thin aluminum sheet metal is pretty cheap compared to a specialty item like you're looking for.

Comment: It would be good to include your intended use, as people may come up with alternatives that you hadn't thought of.

Comment: Folding might be an option but a photo would probably get similar or better answers without a photo we may have ideas that could work but be unrealistic for 200’ or not able to mount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two thoughts

**First** - "edge molding" or "rubber trim" comes in a variety of sizes, types, hardness, shapes, and prices. [Here are just two examples taken from many](https://www.mcmaster.com/edge-molding/rubber-trim-7/) from one of many vendors - not a recommendation
[image] [image]

Second - depending on the application some type of tape (duct tape, weatherproofing tape etc.) might work folded over the edge.

Answer (score 3):

I second Nate's comment that folding the edges is your best bet - it'll give you a small, slightly rounded edge, instead of a sharp edge, and it will stiffen your panel. The drawback is that you probably need a sheet-metal brake to make this happen in anything resembling a neat, time efficient fashion, especially for 200 copies.

This is a small portable brake, bigger counter top & freestanding models are also available:

[image]
<sup>Image courtesy of HarborFreight.com. No endorsement implied. However, for your one-time use, this one may be right up your alley, so the endorsement is, basically, intended.</sup>

If, for whatever reason, you cannot get your hands on a small brake and can't find a local shop that'll do it for you, I'd suggest some clear rubber hose, something like refrigerator line. You can buy whatever diameter best suits your needs, then "just" run a slit down the length of the tube and slide your sheet metal in.

I say "just" because this will be time consuming, but it shouldn't be difficult. A sharp utility knife will easily cut the tubing to length, then will also allow you to slit it. It shouldn't matter too much if your cut wanders a bit (i.e. doesn't go straight down the length of the tube), as the tube itself will happily twist to line up the slit with the edge of the sheet metal.

The tubing is cheap enough that you can buy enough for a couple of trials to see if it will work for you, and you won't be out much if it doesn't.

Comment: You can use this type of break for very long sheets of metal.  Just bend a few degrees, move the break, bend a few degrees, move the break, etc., until you reach the end.  The start over bending a few more degrees this time.  Repeat until you reach the desired angle.

Answer (score 0):

Get a 100 foot garden hose and split it in twain